# How to make apt-clone work with apt-offline?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

My goal is to clone a Ubuntu system's current packages onto another machine that may or may not be connected to the internet. On the target machine the end result should be all packages of the source machine with package version at least or greater than source.

I was able to script something with apt-offline, however it seems apt-clone is a much more elegant solution. Any ideas how I can have apt-clone be pointed to a USB drive or a tar.gz as package sources?